Group properties of density of state for i.i.d. particles microcanonical ensembles
For a $2N$ particle non-interacting gas, we could arbitrarily divide the gas into 2 sets of $N$ particles.
Then the density of states for each one is,
$$
D(N_A, V, U_A) = h^{-N} \int d^Nq~d^Np ~ \delta(H_{q,p} - U_A)
$$
$$
D(N_B, V, U_B) = h^{-N} \int d^Nq~d^Np ~ \delta(H_{q,p} - U_B).
$$
It would seem like the total density of states should be something like this,
$$
D(N, V, U) = \frac{N!}{N_A! N_B!} \int dU_A dU_B ~ \delta(U - U_A - U_B)
$$
where $D$ must be the same function throughout or at least satisfy some kind of group property.
Has this been studied?

Consider to spell out acronyms.

This cannot work, for it ought to run into Gibbs paradox. Also, why are you defining the density of states this way?
